# jQuery table / list context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I am looking for an intuitive js plug in for table rows. Something similar to Sharepoint list view, where when hovering over a table row the row gets highlighted and when clicking the row a context menu appears at a fixed position.

I am developing in ASP.net and prefer jQuery since the plugins are always easy to use.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's all-in-one plug-in that offers such functionality.
You could try to combine this http://15daysofjquery.com/examples/zebra/ and some other jQuery plugin providing you with desired action on click (either left-click or right-click).

Answer (score 0):

http://www.trirand.com/blog/ might have all the functionality you need.